# Как сделать фиксированную кнопку, чтобы она не ложилась под количество букв в строке

Tags: html, css

То есть, если я уберу названия кнопок, то кнопка просто превратится в ничто)

```
                    <div class="buttons">
                        <a href="#" class="nubex"><img src="img/wind.png" alt="" width="50px" height="40px"></a>
                        <a href="#" class="nubex"><img src="img/wind.png" alt="" width="50px" height="40px">Чистка пыли</a>
                        <a href="#" class="nubex"><img src="img/wind.png" alt="" width="50px" height="40px">Замена термопасты</a>
                        <a href="#" class="nubex"><img src="img/wind.png" alt="" width="50px" height="40px">Замена комплектующих</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="buttons">
                        <a href="#" class="nubex"><img src="img/wind.png" alt="" width="50px" height="40px">Переустановка Windows</a>
                        <a href="#" class="nubex"><img src="img/wind.png" alt="" width="50px" height="40px">Переустановка Windows</a>
                        <a href="#" class="nubex"><img src="img/wind.png" alt="" width="50px" height="40px">Переустановка Windows</a>
                        <a href="#" class="nubex"><img src="img/wind.png" alt="" width="50px" height="40px">Переустановка Windows</a>
                    </div>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
a.nubex {
width: 100%;
color: #fff;
user-select: none; /* Убираем текстовое выделение */
text-decoration: none;  /* Убираем подчеркивание */
outline: none; /* Убираем контур вокруг ссылки */
background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); /* Цвет фона */
padding: 40px 20px; /* Отступ от текста до рамки */
border-radius: 5px;
}
a.nubex:active {
background-color: #ee6206; /* Цвет кнопки при нажатии */
}
a.nubex:hover {
background-color: #1f5eb4;
} /* Цвет кнопки при наведении курсора */
```

Comment: css свойство `width`
 https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/width

Comment: не понятно..  можно поподробнее? в чем суть вопроса?

Comment: Хочу, чтобы кнопки не вставали под размер строки, а стояли как я их зафиксирую, например свойством width, но к чему это свойство применить?

Comment: к классу `nubex` или `a.nubex`

Comment: Спасибо, сейчас попробую.

Comment: Почему-то не действует это свойство на a.nubex и просто nubex.

Comment: добавьте в свой вопрос css-код станицы, так проще будет ответить

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/y384br1b/1/ или https://jsfiddle.net/y384br1b/2/

Comment: Добавьте еще display: inline-block; . Элементы, которые относятся к inline не поддерживают width, height

Answer (score 0):

Добавил в CSS код в класс a.nubex

```
min-width: 250px;
display: inline-block;
```

и всё встало как надо.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]